# Q: Path (ProgramFiles)\my folder

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application

I want to make a link for my new folder in program files in VB.NET

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (Not Directory.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\UniWin Activator")) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles + "\UniWin Activator")
    End If
    File.Create(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles + "\UniWin Activator\Dont-show-again.txt").Dispose()
End Sub
```

Can someone modify this for me please?

what i want with this code is:

1- if the folder `(Program Files Location)\UniWin Activator` not created then create it

2- create text file `Dont-show-again.txt` under the folder `(Program Files Location)\UniWin Activator`

Comment: What do you want the button click to do?

Comment: what needs correcting?  does it work? (probably not - you need admin rights to mess with Program Files)  what you want might be better left to the installer

Comment: @Plutonix is right. You need Administrator Privilleges to access (most) special directories.

Comment: @Plutonix i already have admin rights, and i dont want an installer.. im doing this to make a file under the folder while the app is running

i have admin rights by the app manifest file (requireAdministrator)

Comment: have you tried running it outside of VS?

Comment: @FarhanAnam yes my old problem is solved but website doesnt allow marking as answered before 24h

Comment: @FarhanAnam ill try now to run outside VS..
EDIT: error when i click on the button (when i run the above code)

Comment: VS says that the error is in the first line of code `Converting from string to type double is invalid`

Comment: OK wait i think i have found the solution i'll test it and let you know please wait for a few mins

Comment: answer posted please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's wrong with your code is that `SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` or any other `SpecialFolder.xx` is actually an integer. `Special Folder` is an enumeration. Thus you have to use `Environment.GetFolderPath()` to get the actual path. `SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` returns a value of 38 while `Environment.GetFolderPath()` returns the correct path (string). Also since you are using the `ProgramFiles\UniWin Activator` path multiple times, store it in a variable. Here is the correct code:-

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim uniWinPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "UniWin Activator")
        If Not Directory.Exists(uniWinPath) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uniWinPath)
        End If
    File.Create(Path.Combine(uniWinPath, "Dont-show-again.txt")).Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: yes now i understand why it wasn't working, thanks
i tried to combine the path into 1 word but i was failing

Comment: that was not the problem you could have used concatenation instead of `Path.Combine` but it was that you had to use `Environment.GetFolderPath()` to get a string out of the 38.